# Slashdot has the attribution story wrong

Tags: support, mit-license

Stack Overflow's plan to change the code license just [made the slashdot frontpage](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/16/01/15/1437231/use-code-from-stack-overflow-you-must-provide-attribution).

Unfortunately, the summary there completely misleads readers about obligations under the current system.

Could someone on the team get in touch with them?

Comment: [Reddit got it wrong too](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/40zlu1/attribution_will_be_required_when_using_code_from/)... Makes me wonder how many folks have been using this site for years and *never noticed there was a license.*

Comment: @Shog9:  You still have people in this day and age believing that everything found on the Internet is free for use without restrictions, so the fact that a lot of users didn't realize there was a license genuinely doesn't surprise me.

Comment: It isn't @Makoto???

Comment: @bluefeet:  I suppose my counter-corollary would be, "You have people copying code from the Internet into their production code base, and these people still have jobs."

Comment: Wow. A lot of people are really pissed off that they're asked to litter their code with links to the site where they got that code. I wonder if they're mad enough to start writing code from scratch.

Comment: As an aside, @Bill... What do you think of trying to put together some sort of a guide for using code on SO? My gut feeling is that no one who needed it would read it, but... It kinda pains me to see so many folks clueless about what amounts to *good hygiene* when it comes to reuse.

Comment: @Shog9 I think that sounds like a good thing to have. Like "How to Ask," even if people don't read it initially, it would be a good resource to link to when it's needed. At a minimum, it should say what's required, and how those requirements benefit the person reusing code.

Comment: Apparently some of them are going to get expert sex changes because of this... I don't see what that will accomplish, but to each their own I guess.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Should probably come in two parts: one being how to recognize the standard licenses and where to check user profile pages for dual-licensing permission, and the other on where to put dual license permission so people find it.

Comment: "Never before was so little understood so wrongly by so many" -- Winston Churchill (revised). At least reddit leads off with a halfway-decent discussion of employer claims to code ownership, instead of the thread of FUD that dives right into the old "it's on the internet, it's public domain" horsemanure.

Comment: Complaining about bad reporting on Slashdot is an utter waste of time. It was never exactly a bastion of journalism, but nowadays it's a cesspool.

Comment: Slashdot is still around?

Comment: @Shog9: *"Makes me wonder how many folks have been using this site for years and never noticed there was a license."* At a guess? 90-95%. I could easily be under-estimating.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Nice one updating the [license question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required) with that banner. Very much the right thing to do.

Comment: This is important. [Someone is *wrong* on the Internet!](https://xkcd.com/386/)

Comment: Oh my god, reading this or the reddit discussion is just awkward and painful.

Comment: If all these people are misunderstading the license change, there's probably a reason. But did we *really* need a license change? `If it ain't broke, don't fix it`.

Comment: Wow, the comments there are fascinating.

Comment: @Basj: The precondition is the notion that it _is_ "broke", and therefore does need fixing. The fact that all these people seem to be under the impression that SO code is currently public domain actually goes to show that there's an even bigger problem than we thought!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't agree. We all know how much we owe to SO for the wonderful answers it offers. But adding one more legal layer is frightening people. I fear all this legal stuff might break the *magic* of this community. Sometimes, things work not so bad, *then* people want to clean lots of things (let's call it "fix something which was not broken") and then...

Comment: @Shog `Makes me wonder how many folks have been using this site for years and never noticed there was a license` looking at the content posting workflow, that seems to be at least partly by design though. Not once in your SO career are you asked to somehow acknowledge the license you are posting under.

Comment: @Basj: In what way is anyone suggesting "adding one more legal layer"?

Comment: Enforcing licenses on copy-pasted code snippits sounds like a losing business strategy.  I convinced my previous employer to allow me to post code here when they were initially against it, because they would get a better result by collaborating with the community instead of trying to enforce copyrights.   That's always been the spirit of SO. If anything, an MIT license is the most flexible open source license for corporations to use

Comment: @glyph: Telling potential contributors that you don't respect their authorship is the losing business strategy.  Stack Overflow can survive with a fraction as many visitors, but it can't survive without experts posting answers.

Comment: What part of the text is misleading? Seems accurate to me.

Comment: People still read Slashdot? (attribution: paraphrased from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314812/slashdot-has-the-attribution-story-wrong?cb=1#comment295095_314812)

Comment: I never knew there is this attribution issue has existed all this long until reading the slashdot post linked here. IMO, the attribution, if any, should go to the OP, not Stack Overflow. Certainly will participate less when this is becoming another github. Good to know.

Comment: @NewWorld The part that the attribution requirement people are complaining about always existed.

Comment: @tinlyx That is noted in the 2nd paragraph of the linekd post. The complaint made by the Slashdot post is that with the new license it's unambigiuous and clearcut that attribution is required in the source code; whereas with the old license that part was a gray area.

Comment: @tinlyx - What happens when the OP is multiple people or "Community Wiki"? You'd rather list out all the user names (which can change over time as well) than just an URL to the post?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Yeah, I'm willing to be that the vast majority of folks who've never been on Meta didn't know about the license.

Comment: @tinlyx the attribution IS to the author. Recommended way to do so is by linking their profile page on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NewWorld: Slashdot summary says "starting on March 1, copying code from Stack Overflow will require you to attribute that code"  That's wrong.  Correct version is "Copying code from Stack Overflow requires you to attribute that code, and for code found in posts made after (was March 1st, new date unknown), that's the only requirement, you no longer have to 'share alike'".  Notice two major problems with the original: First, that the attribution requirement does not spring into being, it's already there.  Second, that posts made before the changeover remain CC BY-SA and require 'share alike'.

Comment: @BenVoigt who's telling contributors that we don't respect their code? all I'm saying is there is a point of diminishing returns when we get into enforcing licenses on copy pasted code snippets.  Small blocks of generic code present an administrative nightmare to attribute. It's good to have the MIT license now, but It's not practical or enforceable to determine at a granular level when a copy-pasted and subsequently modified block of text is no longer covered under the license.  Ultimately, ownership of numbers raises some fundamental questions.

Comment: @glyph: It seems that you don't understand that we are only talking about licensing copyrighted code.  Under the Berne Convention, all works of a certain minimal complexity automatically have copyright reserved to their author/creator or their designee.  "ownership of numbers" does not even enter into it, because they are not sufficiently complex to be copyright in the first place.

Comment: @BSMP technical difficulties like multiple authors shouldn't change anything about authorship. SO is a wonderful platform to share, but it's just a platform.

Comment: @BenVoigt Regarding the first point, as I've said, the attribution requirement in the CC license was a lot more ambiguous and more of a grey area, whereas the MIT license is a lot more concrete so it can described that essentially attribution is actually required now. Regarding the 2nd point, that's a qualification: the SlashDot post is a summary: it doesn't have space for the whole article. The whole point is that it links to the complete source with all the details and qualifications.

Comment: Stop trying to excuse your copyright violations with "dear me so confusing".  The CC BY-SA rules are quite straightforward. The only problem is identifying whether copied snippets are complex enough to need a license, and the MIT-lite plan makes that worse, not better.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[I left a comment](http://developers.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=8620339&cid=51307691). Not holding out a lot of hope for it, but... worth a shot.